# LitElement : When Template is defined as const, how to call functions

Tags: typescript, lit-element, lit-html

When template is defined in separate file, no able to call function in component.
But if the template is defined directly like return render html`call this.funct` it works.
How to call function when template is defined in separate file.

**Component.ts**

```
import { LitElement, html} from 'lit-element';
import { cTemplate } from './template/ctemplate';

@customElement('card-form')
export class cardFormComponent extends LitElement {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return cTemplate;
  }

  createRenderRoot() {
    return this;
  }

  validateForm() {
    alert('ok');
  }
}


**tempalate.ts**


import {  html } from 'lit-element';

export const cTemplate = html`
 <div>
        <button class="button" @click="${this.validateForm}">Validate</button>
      </div>
';
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can not put the template into a separate file at all. The whole approach relies upon rendering the content by calling `render()`. If you define the template in a constant like that, that template string will be evaluated only once (opposed to each call of `render()`) and not changed later on.

Comment: What if you do `cTemplate.bind(this)` in `render?

Comment: @abraham You can't bind cTemplate since it isn't a function. 
What you could try is to make cTemplate a function that returns the html snippet, bind that and then call that function in render.

Comment: lit-html "templates" are just JavaScript functions - you can absolutely put them in separate files all you want, just like any other JavaScript.

The problem above is that the template is never called.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're putting the template into another file but I imagine your real use case is more complex or you're trying to re-use the same template in multiple components.

Either way, before trying to answer how you could make your exact example work, I would recommend reading up on smart vs dumb components. In short, this template knows too much, it knows that there should be a function like validateForm to call when the button is clicked (this tightly couples the template to the component, so it sort of defeats the point of keeping it in different files). A perhaps better approach (if you want to decouple things) is to provide a callback to run when the button is clicked. The callback could be any action to take when the button is clicked.

Now, to fix your example (as well as perhaps make it more flexible) you have to understand what `this` means in JavaScript. `this` is the current context of your function and depending on how your function is created and called it will be set to different things.

In your `template.ts` file you don't have a function (although the way modules are transpiled it will become one) but you still have a `this`, in this context `this` is the context of the module itself. So inside your template snippet you're trying to call `module.validateForm` which doesn't exist. The reason for this is that you're creating the snippet when the module is being loaded, not when it is needed for `render`.

The first step in the solution is to create the snippet in a function instead and export that, so that it can be called inside of render to prepare the snippet. This way you could start to control what `this` is inside the function.
I am not certain if the next step is needed, but if `this` still isn't the context of your component class, you will need to use `bind` to force `this` to be the component class.

See a full example below:
**Component.ts**

```
import { LitElement, html} from 'lit-element';
import { cTemplate } from './template/ctemplate'; // cTemplate is now a function, not a const

@customElement('card-form')
export class cardFormComponent extends LitElement {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.cTemplate = cTemplate.bind(this); // This step forces this inside of the cTemplate function to be the component class. This might not be needed.
  }

  render() {
    return this.cTemplate(); // .bind() returns a new function, which we save on the component class so we use this in order to call the new version which has this = component class
  }

  validateForm() {
    alert('ok');
  }
}


**tempalate.ts**


import {  html } from 'lit-element';

export function cTemplate() {
    return html`
        <div>
            <button class="button" @click="${this.validateForm}">Validate</button>
        </div>
    ';
}
```

For the improvement:
**BetterComponent.ts**

```
import { LitElement, html} from 'lit-element';
import { cTemplate } from './template/ctemplate';

@customElement('card-form')
export class cardFormComponent extends LitElement {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.cTemplate = cTemplate.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return this.cTemplate(this.validateForm, 'Validate');
  }

  validateForm() {
    alert('ok');
  }
}


**tempalate.ts**


import {  html } from 'lit-element';

export function cTemplate(onClick, label) {
    // cTemplate is now a function that creates a snippet for a button that calls a function when the button is clicked (or, a button "component")
    return html`
        <div>
            <button class="button" @click="${onClick}">${label}</button>
        </div>
    ';
}
```

I would still underline that this feels like a bit of a strange pattern. If you were looking to create a button component that you can reuse then I would instead make that a full web component of it's own. Where `render` returns what cTemplate does right now, and inside of the cardForm I would make `render` simply create something like:

```
html`<my-button label="${'Validate'}" .onClick="${this.validateForm}"></my-button>`
```

You could also make `my-button` fire a `click` event like a real button and use @click instead.

Comment: First, thanks for the detailed explanation. brings more clarity to the scope of "this" here. Main purpose was to make my component clutter free, having html and logical code in the same file makes it quite big and less readable in the real scenarios.  This pattern i followed by an existing app. but looks like there the intention was to just display the param values in the template , but nothing like calling the comp functions.  This makes very clear what exactly is happening, thanks

Comment: There are two big schools to that, as exemplified by for example Angular and React. LitElement I think tries to follow the more "whole component" approach, if the file becomes too big, you likely would benefit from breaking it into smaller pieces with less responsibility in each. This is true for Angular as well but the framework doesn't make you realize this quite as quickly.

Comment: LitElement is just JavaScript. We encourage you to organize your code however you like best. One file. Many small files. Shared templates. Whatever works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the problems in your code snippet:

1. You're not defining a template function in template.ts, you're just creating a non-changing template result. Templates should usually be functions.
2. You're not calling a template in `render()`.
3. Standalone template functions shouldn't use `this`.

Here is how I would write it instead:

```js
import { LitElement, html} from 'lit-element';
import { cTemplate } from './template/ctemplate';

@customElement('card-form')
export class cardFormComponent extends LitElement {

  render() {
    return cTemplate(this.validateForm, 'Validate');
  }

  validateForm() {
    alert('ok');
  }
}

/** template.ts **/
import {  html } from 'lit-element';

export const cTemplate = (onClick, label) => html`
  <div>
    <button class="button" @click="${onClick}">${label}</button>
  </div>
`;
```

Note that I don't bind the template function or the click handler. Instead pass in the data as arguments to the template, and LitElement will take care of calling the event handlers with the host element as the `this` value.

Comment: Thanks Justin for taking time to clarify :) Makes things more clear.